# How to filter and sort Items using Model and QTableView

Tags: python, qt, model, pyqt, qtableview

There are three `QTableViews`: A, B, C. All three share the same SourceModel.

There are three column names: "Items A", "Items B" and "Items C" stored in `self.columnNames` list.

Each `QTableView` was assigned an instance of the same `ProxyModel` with proxy's objectName set to "proxyA", "proxyB" and "proxyC".

I want the left-side `QTableView` to list only the items "A" using a single column with its header named "Items A".

The middle `tableViewB` should only list "Items_B" with the column-header called  "Items B".

And the third tableView should list only items "C" with the column name set to "Items C".

The source code is below. I really wanna know how to do it.

[image]

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys, os

class Model(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args):
        QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent, *args)
        self.items =[ 
                    ['Item_A_0','Item_A_12','Item_C_330'],
                    ['Item_C_20','Item_B_11','Item_B_12'],
                    ['Item_C_101','Item_A_24','Item_B_77']
                    ]
        self.columnNames=['Items A', 'Items B', 'Items C']

    def headerData(self, col, orientation, role):
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self.columnNames[col]

    def flags(self, index):
        return Qt.ItemIsEnabled | Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEditable

    def rowCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.items)       
    def columnCount(self, parent):
        return len(self.columnNames)

    def data(self, index, role):
        if not index.isValid(): return QVariant()
        row=index.row()
        column=index.column()

        if row>len(self.items): return QVariant()        
        if column>len(self.items[row]): return QVariant()

        columnName=self.headerData(column, Qt.Horizontal, Qt.DisplayRole)

        if role == Qt.EditRole or role == Qt.DisplayRole:

            return QVariant(self.items[row][column])


        return QVariant()

    def setData(self, index, value, role=Qt.EditRole):
        if index.isValid():            
            if role == Qt.EditRole:
                row = index.row()
                column=index.column()
                if row>len(self.items) or column>len(self.items[row]):
                    return False
                else:

                    self.items[row][column]=value  
                    return True
        return False

class Proxy(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Proxy, self).__init__()

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, row, parent):
        sourceModel=self.sourceModel()
        columns=sourceModel.columnCount(QModelIndex())        

        return True

class MyWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        tablemodel=Model(self) 
        proxyA=Proxy()
        proxyA.setObjectName('proxyA')
        proxyA.setSourceModel(tablemodel)              
        tableviewA=QTableView(self) 
        tableviewA.setModel(proxyA)    

        proxyB=Proxy()
        proxyB.setObjectName('proxyB')
        proxyB.setSourceModel(tablemodel)              
        tableviewB=QTableView(self) 
        tableviewB.setModel(proxyB)

        proxyC=Proxy()
        proxyC.setObjectName('proxyC')
        proxyC.setSourceModel(tablemodel)              
        tableviewC=QTableView(self) 
        tableviewC.setModel(proxyC)

        layout=QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(tableviewA)
        layout.addWidget(tableviewB)
        layout.addWidget(tableviewC)
        self.setLayout(layout)      

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I think you need to implement the `QSortFilterProxyModel::filterAcceptsColumn()` function in your proxy model, so that it will return true only for those column you need to show. Each proxy model instance should be initialized with a flag that will indicate which column to filter.

Comment: `filterAcceptsRow()` is already implemented. But it returns True for everything. Please show how `filterAcceptsRow()` could be used to achieve this goal.

Comment: As I said, you need to implement **filterAcceptsColumn()** and not `filterAcceptsRow()`.

Comment: In the same way, as you did for filterAcceptRow() function. For example: `def filterAcceptsColumn(self, column, parent): if column == 0: return true else: return false`.

Comment: The problem is the `filterAcceptsColumn()` is only filters based on column number and self.objectName(). For example: `if self.objectName()=='proxyA' and 'Item_A' in sourceModel.columnNames[column] : return True`. But I need it to be able to filter by item's name as well which is not available. `filterAcceptsColumn()` doesn't know anything about the item name.

Comment: In order to perform a filtering needed the Proxy's `filterAccepts...()` methods need to know three things: the objectName of the proxy itself which is `self.objectName()`, the ColumnName which is `self.sourceModel.columnNames[column]` and the item's name (which is not available) inside of the `filterAccepts` method.

Comment: The sourceModel's `data()` method processes each QModelIndex in a table. So it is possible to get the `item's name` and a `column Name` using `index.column()`. But `sourceModel` doesn't know anything about the `objectName` of the ProxyModel....